# Select range of lines in native linux text-editors (gedit, pluma, nemo)

Tags: gedit, text-processing, text-editor, nemo, pluma

I have a very large text file, and I want to select part of the text (range of lines. Example: from line 10000 to line 40000 and the text has 100 thousand lines). But I do not see any option in these editors (gedit, pluma, nemo) that allows me to make this selection (only "select all or Ctrl+A" option).

I would like to know how to do it and in case they do not allow, what other similar text editor (GUI) exists that allows me to make this selection.

thanks

**Clarification**:

I already know the alternatives in the command line. The answer I ask is only in the text editors mentioned (or in other similar ones, native Linux applications. Exclude "vim" or "nano".)

I have installed the additional plugins of [gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-install.html.en) and [pluma](https://github.com/yselkowitz/pluma-plugins), but I also do not see that they have this possibility of selection

This option [can be found in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490968/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad). I installed a clone called [notepadqq, but it does not have this option](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/393)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[In sublime text](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/large-selection-highlight-or-select-range-by-line-number/13879/2):

```
Ctrl-G to go to the last line you want to select, by number.
Edit > Mark > Set Mark to set your selection-end marker.
Ctrl-G (or Ctrl-Home) to go to the first line you want to select.
Edit > Mark > Select to Mark
```

[In vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97473):

`go to line should select text from the current cursor when holding down shift`

Comment: Links change all the time. Please provide the essential steps in your answer so that one can replicate the solution without clicking on the link. Keep the links as references. [Link only answers may be deleted.](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers) I am down voting this as a link only answer.

Comment: answer update. if you are not satisfied, please notify me to expand it even more

Comment: I have removed my down vote. Feel free to expand and improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

vim can certainly do this: in command mode, enter `10000G` hit `V` then `40000G`. Voilà, requested selection.

However, *what do you want to do with the selection*?

Comment: select from the line (example 1000) to another line (example 4000) and delete them, to insert in this place other lines of another text.  I would prefer it not to be with vim

Comment: Well, pick an editor and ask a question about how to do this specific action with this specific editor. Don't ask countless strangers to read your mind.

Comment: Already did. It is in the question (nemo, gedit, pluma)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (one of several methods):

head -number_of_lines < file.txt > file.new